# $g\left( x \right)=3-\sqrt { x+3 } $

Tags: functions

To be honest, I suck at math, so that's why I'm here, to ask you guys a question.

The function is $g\left( x \right)=3-\sqrt { x+3 } $. When the value of $x$ is equal to $-3y$ will equal $3$. If $x$ is equal to $-1$ $y$ is equal to $1$. My question is the following: How can I calculate the value of $y$ when knowing the value of $x$ using the function above?

Comment: Do you want to call it $g$ or $y$? Make up your mind!

Comment: What is $y$? Are you saying that $y=g(x)$?

Comment: @TonyK That doesn't seem necessary, especially to a new user.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but y = g(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3-\sqrt{x+3}$ when $x=-3$ is found as follows.

$x+3 = 0$

$\sqrt{x+3} = \sqrt{0} = 0$

$3-\sqrt{x+3} = 3-\sqrt{0} = 3-0 = 3$.

Or when $x=-1$:

$x+3 = -1+3 = 2$

$\sqrt{x+3} = \sqrt{2}$

$3-\sqrt{x+3} = 3-\sqrt{2}$, and there's no simpler way to represent this.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I get it now.